# how to put a gap at the beginning and end of my grid using flexbox?

Tags: css

I am trying to put a `50px gap` to my grid, but I would like to have the same gap between each `div`, that is to say that there is also `50px` from the beginning of the first div to the end of the last `div`. How can I do it?

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow:auto;
  gap:50px;
}

.flex div{
 width:90px;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both pseudo element and leave them empty. You will trigger the gap:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  gap: 50px;
}

.flex div {
  width: 90px;
  background: red;
}

.flex:before,
.flex:after {
  content:"";
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .flex{
      display:flex;
      width:100%;
      background:yellow;
      align-items:center;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      overflow:auto;
    }

    .flex div{
     width:90px;
     background:red;
     margin-right: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
</div>
```

like this?

You can also use other flex properties like

```css
        .flex{
          display:flex;
          width:100%;
          background:yellow;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
          align-items:center;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          overflow:auto;
        }

        .flex div{
         width:90px;
         background:red;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="flex">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>

    </div>
```

or if you want the first element aswell

```css
        .flex{
          display:flex;
          width:100%;
          background:yellow;
          align-items:center;
          flex-wrap: nowrap;
          overflow:auto;
        }

        .flex div{
         width:90px;
         background:red;
         margin-right: 50px;
        }

        .flex div:first-child{
         margin-left: 50px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="flex">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add on the `div.flex` a left and right padding equals to the gap between child elements.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  --gap: 50px;
  gap: var(--gap);
  padding: 0 var(--gap);
}

.flex div {
  width: 90px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>hello</div>
</div>
```